# Наследование и глобальные переменные

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть 2 класса B и C, унаследованных от A. Всё что они делают - это присваивают переменной собственной переменной значение **tmp** от родительского класса. Выглядит это как-то так:

```
tmp = 0

class A:
    # something here 

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        b_class_tmp = self.tmp


class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        c_class_tmp = self.tmp


print(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)
```

Нужно реализовать класс А так, что бы увеличивать значение **tmp** на 1 при каждом его вызове (явном и неявном). То есть вывод в консоль в данном случае должен быть **0 1 2**.

Изначально я сделал это так:

```
tmp = 0

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        global tmp
        self.tmp = tmp
        tmp += 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        b_class_tmp = self.tmp


class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        c_class_tmp = self.tmp

print(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)
```

Но классы B и С изменять нельзя, что поставило меня в некоторое затруднение
Буду признателен за помощь

Comment: а почему 0, 1, 2? Если вы в самом принте тоже обращаетесь к переменной, а значит она должна увеличиться

Comment: Тут что-то сильно не так... `self.tmp` - не существует в момент вызова `__init__`. Ссылка `*_class_tmp` будет просто отброшена после выполнения `__init__`. Где должен храниться `tmp`? Глобальная переменная? Объект класса `A`? Объект `A()`? В примере `(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)` уже 5 вызовов `tmp`. Т.е. вывод должен быть `0 2 4`.

Comment: @anton-abrosimov, пример абстрактный. С ```*_class_tmp``` делать ничего не нужно. Касательно переменной ```tmp``` - не ясно, с этим вопросом я, собственно, и пришел

Comment: @anton-abrosimov, нет. Возможно двусмысленно написал в вопросе. Переменная ```tmp``` должна увеличиваться при вызове конструктора класса ```A```. То есть всего три раза

Comment: `tmp` должна быть идентична для всех объектов родительского и дочерних классов, или каждый сохраняет текущее значение?

Comment: Каждый класс должен сохранять текущее значение. ```print(A().tmp , B().tmp, C().tmp, tmp)``` >>> ```0 1 2 2```

Comment: А, вообще, пожалуй, не важно. Суть задачи в правильном выводе. На счет реализации основное требование - не менять классы B и C. Остальное на усмотрение. Так что буду счастлив посмотреть несколько вариантов

Comment: Если увеличение должно быть именно в конструкторе `A`, то первая проблема в том, что классы `B` и `C` его не вызывают. В их конструкторы необходимо добавить: `super().__init__()`

Comment: Да. Изначально я так и сделал. Но позже обнаружил в задании, что эти классы изменять нельзя. Что и завело меня в тупик

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно это то, что вы хотели:

```
class A:
    _tmp = 0

    @staticmethod
    def get_tmp():
        A._tmp += 1
        return A._tmp - 1

    @property
    def tmp(self):
        return self.get_tmp()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        b_class_tmp = self.tmp


class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        c_class_tmp = self.tmp


print(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)
print(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)
```

Результат:

```
0 2 4
5 7 9
```

Только будьте аккуратнее. Это черная магия, способствующая непредсказуемым ошибкам, если вы забудете, что определение `A` меняется по ходу исполнения. Ну и от коллег можно будет много нового о себе узнать за такие фокусы.

Способ без магии:

```
class Counter:
    _value = -1

    def __call__(self):
        self._value += 1
        return self._value

counter = Counter()

class A:
    _tmp = counter

    @property
    def tmp(self):
        return self._tmp()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        b_class_tmp = self.tmp

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        c_class_tmp = self.tmp


print(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)
print(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)
```

Результат аналогичен.

```
class Counter:
    _value = -1

    def __call__(self):
        return self._value

    def up(self):
        self._value += 1
        return self._value

counter = Counter()

class A:
    _tmp = counter

    def __init__(self):
        self._tmp.up()  # Увеличение счетчика.

    @property
    def tmp(self):  # Вывод значения счетчика.
        return self._tmp()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # Вызов метода родительского класса.
        b_class_tmp = self.tmp  # Передача текущего значения счетчика в локальную переменную.


class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        c_class_tmp = self.tmp


print(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)
print(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)
```

Результат:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
```

Вариант активации счетчика при сборке класса:

```
class CounterMeta(type):
    _value = 0

    def __new__(cls, name, parents, attrs):    
        print('Creating class: ', name)
        attrs['tmp'] = cls._value
        cls._value += 1
        return super().__new__(cls, name, parents, attrs)

class A(metaclass=CounterMeta):
    pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        b_class_tmp = self.tmp

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        c_class_tmp = self.tmp

print(A().tmp)
print(B().tmp)
print(C().tmp)
print(C().tmp)
print(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)
```

Прошу обратить внимание на очередность в выводе. Сначала собираются классы.

```
Creating class:  A
Creating class:  B
Creating class:  C
0
1
2
2
0 1 2
```

Счетчик увеличивается при создании объектов:

```
CUR_TMP = 0

class A:
    _tmp = 0
    _init = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.tmp

    @property
    def tmp(self):
        if not self._init:
            self._init = True
            global CUR_TMP
            self._tmp = CUR_TMP
            CUR_TMP += 1
            return self._tmp
        else:
            return self._tmp

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        b_class_tmp = self.tmp

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        c_class_tmp = self.tmp

print(A().tmp)
b = B()
print(b.tmp)
print(b.tmp)
print(C().tmp)
print(b.tmp)
print(C().tmp)
print(A().tmp, B().tmp, C().tmp)
```

Результат:

```
0
1
1
2
1
3
4 5 6
```

Comment: Надеюсь, что когда у меня появятся коллеги - такие задачи я смогу решать уже сам)
А пока что, не могли бы вы мне подсказать, почему tmp увеличивается на 2, а не на 1 за один вызов конструктора класса А?

Comment: При вызове конструктора `A` `tmp` вообще не меняется. У `A` нет `__init__`. И уточни, о каком примере мы говорим, если нужны подробности.

Comment: О том, который "без магии"

Comment: В примере без магии `tmp` увеличивается в момент обращения к методу `.tmp`. В `__init__` классов `B`, `C` и в теле `print`.